What's wrong with my script! Shading Nodes won't place!
Currently trying to wrap my head around why my script won't place my Brightness/Contrast Node in the desired location and configuration.
Shaders for all materials are currently arranged and directly aligned like the screenshot below, done successfully also using python

This is the desired result below, to simply place a Brightness/Contrast node to the left of the Principled BDSF

# Create the Brightness/Contrast node
    brightness_contrast = nodes.new("ShaderNodeBrightContrast")
    brightness_contrast.location = (principled.location[0] - 400, principled.location[1])
    brightness_contrast.inputs['Brightness'].default_value = -0.100  # Set Brightness to -0.100
    brightness_contrast.inputs['Contrast'].default_value = 0.100     # Set Contrast to 0.100

# Find the texture node (if it exists)
    texture = next((n for n in nodes if isinstance(n, bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage)), None)
    if texture is not None:
    # Connect Base Color of the texture to the input color of the Brightness/Contrast node
           mat.node_tree.links.new(texture.outputs['Color'], brightness_contrast.inputs['Color'])
    
    # Connect the output color of the Brightness/Contrast node to the Base Color input of the Principled BSDF
    mat.node_tree.links.new(brightness_contrast.outputs['Color'], principled.inputs['Base Color'])


there is no input Brightness, try this
import bpy

node_tree = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree
principled_node = next((node for node in node_tree.nodes if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED'), None)

brightness_contrast = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeBrightContrast")
brightness_contrast.location = (principled_node.location.x - 200, principled_node.location.y)
brightness_contrast.inputs['Bright'].default_value = -0.1
brightness_contrast.inputs['Contrast'].default_value = 0.1

texture_node = next((node for node in node_tree.nodes if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE'), None)
if texture_node:
    node_tree.links.new(texture_node.outputs['Color'], brightness_contrast.inputs['Color'])

node_tree.links.new(brightness_contrast.outputs['Color'], principled_node.inputs['Base Color'])


Alternatively can also access inputs by index eg brightness_contrast.inputs[1]
